# How to overload an Interface with a generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overriding

When I use a generic interface, which is an overload of a normal interface I get an error the property of the normal interface is not implemented.

Example:

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    string Bar1{ get; set; }
    string Bar2{ get; set; }
}
public interface IInterface2
{
    IInterface1 Foo{ get; }
}
public interface IInterface3<T>:IInterface2 where T:IInterface1
{
    new T Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Class1<T> : IInterface3<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    public T Foo { get; set; }
}
```

> ERROR: 'Class1' does not implement interface member 'IInterface2.Foo'. 'Class1.Foo' cannot implement 'IInterface2.Foo' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IInterface1'.

But T is always of type IInterface1. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1:**
If I remove the IInterface3, I cannot return T from my class

**Edit2:**
When I change Foo of Class1 to return IInterface1 instead of T, I'll still get an error

**Edit3:**
When I change IInterface3 and Class1 to return the same object in 2 ways it does work.
I only want Foo and Foo1 in Class1 combined.
(btw: removed the setter of IInterface2. I don't need it)

**Solution:**
The answers of fejesjoco and Rik got me thinking and helped me in this final solution:

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    string Bar1 { get; set; }
    string Bar2 { get; set; }
}
public interface IInterface2
{
    IInterface1 Foo { get; }
}
public interface IInterface3<T>:IInterface2 where T:IInterface1
{
    new T Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Class1<T> : IInterface3<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    private T _foo;
    T IInterface3<T>.Foo { get { return _foo; } set { _foo = value; } }
    IInterface1 IInterface2.Foo { get { return _foo; } }
}
```

or

```
public class Class1<T> : IInterface3<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    public T Foo { get; set; }
    IInterface1 IInterface2.Foo { get { return Foo; } }
}
```

The prove of the pudding is in the tasting:

```
public class ImplemetationA : IInterface1
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string Bar2 { get; set; }

    // some extra definitions here
}

public class ImplemetationB : IInterface1
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string Bar2 { get; set; }

    // some extra definitions here
}

public class Problem : Class1<ImplemetationA>
{
    public ImplemetationA Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ProblemSolved
{
    public IInterface2 Method1()
    {
        var solvedProblem = new Problem();
        solvedProblem.Foo = new ImplemetationA();
        return solvedProblem;
    }
    public void Method2()
    {
        IInterface2 solvedProblem = Method1();
        var result = solvedProblem.Foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: im not quite sure what you do in `IInterface3` where you call `new` to `T` in inteface scope. I havve never seen this before. Is this legal? Why do you do it, if you dont store it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But T is always of type IInterface1

Not exactly. T will be a type that implements IInterface1, but it will never be exactly IInterface1. Member signatures must match the interface specification exactly. You have to implement a property with the name Foo and type IInterface1. You can use explicit interface implementation and call into the other Foo, this way they will work the same way.

Comment: "Not exactly. T will be a type that implements IInterface1" thats what I mend. As you can see in Edit3, you can return T as Interface1. Than why does it have to match exactly?<br>

Comment: updated: "Not exactly. T will be a type that implements IInterface1" thats what I mend. As you can see in Edit3, you can return T as Interface1. Than why does it have to match exactly? I can't use explicit interface in the original example, because the compiler wants me to implement both. mmm, wait explicit call both. Lets test that. Yes that works. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I think what you are looking for is this:

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    string Bar1{ get; set; }
    string Bar2{ get; set; }
}
public interface IInterface2<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    T Foo{ get; set; }
}

public class Class1<T> : IInterface2<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    public T Foo { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit2**
If you need to also have a non-generic interface, you can try this:

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    string Bar1{ get; set; }
    string Bar2{ get; set; }
}
public interface IInterface2
{
    IInterface1 Foo{ get; }
}
public interface IInterface3<T>:IInterface2 where T:IInterface1
{
    new T Foo { get; set; } // hide the non-generic IInterface2.Foo
}

public class Class1<T> : IInterface3<T> where T : IInterface1
{
    public T Foo { get; set; }
    IInterface1 IInterface2.Foo { get { return Foo; }} // explicitely implement IInterface2.Foo
}
```

This compiles, but I'm not 100% sure this also gives the desired behavior.

**Original Answer**

I was typing almost exactly what [fejesjoco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20514993/5409) already answered. I'd just like to illustrate *why* this is a problem.

Consider a few additional classes:

```
public class ImplemetationA : IInterface1
{
    string Bar1{ get; set; }
    string Bar2{ get; set; }

    // some extra definitions here
}

public class ImplemetationB : IInterface1
{
    string Bar1{ get; set; }
    string Bar2{ get; set; }

    // some extra definitions here
}

public class Problem : Class1<ImplemetationA>
{
     public ImplemetationA Foo {get; set;}
}
```

So the class `Problem` implements the interface as you defined it. The issue is that `Problem` still has to implement the non-generic interface `IInterface2`. According to your logic, this requirement is fulfilled by the already present property `Foo` in class `Problem`, because "T is always of type IInterface1". But what happens why we try to do this:

```
var myProblem = new Problem(); // remember, Problem : Class1<ImplemetationA>
var myImplB = new ImplementationB();
myProblem.Foo = myImplB;
```

`Problem` implements `IInterface2`, and since `ImplementationB` implements `IInterface1`, this should be allowed, but obviously, there's a type conflict here because there is no implicit conversion between `ImplemetationB` and `ImplemetationA`.

Comment: Thx for your illustrating answer. To 'my logic' this also doesn't work, as myProblem.Foo is of Type ImplementationA, so myImplB can't be assigned to it. In Edit3 I show that Foo and Foo1 return the same Object. I only want 1 property instead of 2.

Comment: With your edited answer, I cannot use IInterface2 without knowing what T is.

Comment: In that case, I think you're stuck with the option you described in your Edit3. You want to be able to access `Foo` both generically and non-generically, so you will have to implement both cases separately.

Comment: I made an addition to my answer, please review.